# How to optimize the following query order by without union

Tags: mysql

I need a logic to search the columns based on the string.

Consider the following query. In the below query i want to search the customer table for the string 'test'. If it is found in customer name column it need to be in the top, followed by the columns found based on customer_slug

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_list` WHERE customer_name = 'test' UNION
SELECT * FROM `customer_list` WHERE customer_slug = 'test'
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM customer_list where customer_name = 'test' or customer_slug = 'test'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM customer_list 
where 'test' in (customer_name, customer_slug)
order by 'test' <> customer_name,
         'test' <> customer_slug
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, IF(customer_name = 'test', 1, 2) AS priority
FROM customer_list
WHERE customer_name = 'test'
OR customer_slug = 'test'
ORDER BY priority
```